# VNC: Translate Qt KeyEvent to usable X11/RFB keysym

Tags: windows, qt, vnc, qkeyevent

Background: I am currently in the process of creating a simple VNC viewer embedded in a QWidget for use on Windows. For this, I compiled the Qt-only VNC version of [KRDC](http://websvn.kde.org/trunk/KDE/kdenetwork/krdc/vnc/) (remote desktop viewer for KDE) as well as its dependency libvncclient on windows. The problem which arose now however lies in the way krdc sends key events over vnc: it simply sends the value of QKeyEvent::nativeVirtualKey(), which on X11 is conveniently already a valid RFB keysym. On Windows however, this is not the case.

Now, to solve this problem, I think the best (and ultimately also portable) way is to translate Qt's QKeyEvent::key() and ::modifier() data back to valid X11/RFB keysyms. This seems somewhat complex though given that I need to pick different keysyms depending on modifier state (XK_a vs XK_A, I've only considered shift so far) as well. Looking into how X11 -> Qt translation is done in Qt's source code didn't really help either.

Might there already be a library or code snippet out there which accomplishes this? Or should I just attempt to write my own (incomplete) translation routine? If so, what would be the best way to go about this and also, are there other caveats related to X11 I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seems like I'm actually blind; there was a reference in krdc's code, right below the e->nativeVirtualKey() statement, referencing another project's [class](http://italc.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.0.9.1/vncview_8cpp-source.html) where they encountered the exact same problem as me:

```
// hmm, either Win32-platform or too old Qt so we have to handle and
// translate Qt-key-codes to X-keycodes
```

I didn't test their solution but it seems solid. As I only discovered this now, I have already written a small routine myself which should work ok for most latin keyboards (but will probably break if the Qt team changes any of the Qt::Key values), if anyone is interested in it: [link](http://pastebin.com/ZBYRPUb2)